# How to create a function that finds number of divisible digits given two parameters

Tags: python

So I want to create a function that takes two ints: n and m. I want the function to return the number of digits in n that are divisible by m. A couple special cases, if one of the digits in n is 0 then it will count it as divisible. I am trying to do this by manipulating n itself but am not sure how to effectively loop through each number of the int to check if it is divisible by m.
Here's what I have so far:

```
def divisible_nums(n, m):
    num_divisible = 0
    while n % 10 in range(1,10):
        last_digit = n % 10
        if last_digit / m == 0:
            num_divisible += 1
            n = n // 10
        else:
            n = n // 10
    return num_divisible
```

It just keeps returning 0, any ideas?

Comment: `while n % 10 in range(1,10):` -- why not just `while n % 10 != 0:`?

Comment: But shouldn't that just be `while n != 0:`?

Comment: The way to test if a number is divisible by another number is `last_digit % m == 0`

Comment: Can you give me an example scenario

Comment: you can also use `for digit in map(int, str(n)):` to iterate through the digits of `n`

Comment: "A couple special cases, if one of the digits in n is 0 then it will count it as divisible." That isn't a special case. `0` *actually is* divisible by whatever `m` value (except 0).

Comment: "while n % 10 in range(1,10):" In what circumstance do you expect this condition not to be met? "if last_digit / m == 0:" In what circumstance do you expect this condition to be met? Try to think about the logic more clearly. Try to explain, in plain English words, step by step, why your program is doing the right thing. It isn't, of course, but the attempt to explain it will help you understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. Your `while` condition is wrong. You'll stop as soon as you get to a 0 digit. It should be `while n != 0:`.
2. Your test for the last digit being divisible by `m` is wrong, you have to use `%`, not `/`.

```
def divisible_nums(n, m):
    num_divisible = 0
    while n != 0:
        last_digit = n % 10
        if last_digit % m == 0:
            num_divisible += 1
        n = n // 10
    return num_divisible
```

Also, `n = n // 10` is the same in both the `if` and `else`, so take it out of the condition and move it into the main body of the loop.